# Need Help to troubleshoot building of custom kernel on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, make, modprobe

I need some help about building a custom kernel on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr). It is not my first time to compile kernels, but I faced the problem to build only on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to build kernel modules with the command `make modules`, it builds the modules on stage2, so not all kernel modules build. It only built a few driver modules.

I tried to troubleshoot this problem by `modprobe` and `insmod i` found that I miss `hello.ko`.
I tried to solve by `modprobe -v hello.ko` or `insmod hello.ko`, but this did not work.
I tried to start by `make -j5`, but it only created modules without any install.

So now, how can I successfully build this kernel?

Comment: In order to install the modules, you need to run 'sudo make modules_install', unless you are making the kernel into a .deb. Then it's a different process.

Comment: im already tried to use the command make modules_install the problme when i use the command sudo make modules the modules is built in stage 2 only it make few drivers modules not all the kernel modules i tried to create hello.c and edited make file this is not work when i checked modprobe there is missing objects its hello.ko itry to fix by adding modprobe -v hello.ko but it told me modprobe: FATAL: Module hello.ko not found.

Comment: doesn't make modules only build the modules currently in use?

Comment: okay, make -j5 worked, all you have to do is run sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

first, run

```
sudo make -j5
```

then, run

```
sudo make install -j5
```

to install it

Comment: thanks i will try it this probleme is started on my new fresh os i found strange something the old configuration i maked on my previous os is the same when i extract my kernel source on the new os and start to make config how this happen i dont know is my harddisk is hacked or what im running os manual encrypted by luks and before install i shred my harddisk and encrypt it

Comment: This is not work